# What is this city that is being shown on a Samsung TV model?

Tags: identify-this, cities, marinas

Does anyone know where this photo was taken? I'm captivated by the channel with the boats in the middle of the city. There was no caption accompanying the photo. Sorry for the bad quality of the image.

[image: TV demo]

Comment: If you're looking to visit something like this, it is a very common sight in European riverside cities. Even my small 20k inhabitants town has one. I know of one in Rotterdam too.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Dusseldorf Marina, Germany!](https://goo.gl/maps/zeySQ4q5d7x)

[image]

Clue here was the white curvy building in the background - searching for 'Frank Gehry marina' helped find this. (At least second time around - there's also a marina right by Gehry's IAC building in NYC which threw me at first...)

Comment: And the picture that Google showed me when I clicked your link was almost identical to the one OP posted.

Comment: Yep this is definitely it - thank you. I commend your search skills ;)

Comment: Also kudos to @phoog for calling me out when I incorrectly guessed NYC first!

Comment: It's called Medienhafen.

Comment: The Google Maps picture sphere even has the boat with the blue cover from the bottom right of the OP's picture in the same place.

Comment: @simbabque: do you mean bottom left?